# Error on sourcing .bashrc, but not when loading it for first time

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-18.04

I'm getting an error from my `.bash_aliases` file when I run `source .bashrc`. *However* when I start up a terminal (I use terminator), the error doesn't show and both `.bashrc` and `.bash_aliases` are properly sourced.

The error I'm getting is:

```
bash: /home/ciaran/.bash_aliases: line 33: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: /home/ciaran/.bash_aliases: line 33: `html ()'
```

This refers to a custom alias I put in place for `pandoc` to convert .md to .html.

There is no error in the function as far as I know, but here's the code anyways:

```
#!/bin/sh

#[...] Regular aliases for ls and stuff
#[...] Other Stuff that is irrelevant

html ()
{
pandoc -f markdown -t html $1 > /home/ciaran/Desktop/r.html
wait
firefox /home/ciaran/Desktop/r.html;
wait
sleep 5
rm /home/ciaran/Desktop/r.html;
}

alias html='html 2>/dev/null'

#=====================================================================================

alias src="clear && source ~/.bashrc"
```

What could cause an error to pop up only when I run `src`?

Am I missing something blatantly obvious?

**EDIT:** I just remembered a detail that might influence Stuff:
I activate an anaconda environment as the last line of `.bashrc`. I don't know if this can cause issues or not, but I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Try changing to `#!/bin/bash` Shebang.

Comment: If you believe `printPretty` isn't relevant, you should remove it from the question. We don't need your exact file: just an exact file that *reproduces your problem*.

Comment: I removed the unnecessary function from the question. thx for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a space in your function declaration.  That's why the syntax error is reporting on that line.

```sh
html () {
pandoc -f markdown -t html $1 > /home/ciaran/Desktop/r.html
wait
firefox /home/ciaran/Desktop/r.html;
wait
sleep 5
rm /home/ciaran/Desktop/r.html;
}
```

See this for clean up.

```sh
print_pretty () 
{ 
    stat -c$'%F\n%n' * | awk -vC0='\033[1;34m' -vC1='\033[00m' -vC2='\033[1;32m' -vC3='\033[1;36m' '/^directory/ {getline LEFT[++DC]; next} {getline RIGHT[++FC]} {for (i=1; i<=FC; i++) {if (system("[ -h " RIGHT[i] " ]") == 0) RIGHT[i]=C3 RIGHT[i]; if (system("[ -x " RIGHT[i] " ]") == 0) RIGHT[i]=C2 RIGHT[i]}} END {for (i=1; i<=(DC>FC?DC:FC); i++) printf "%-50s%s\n", C0 LEFT[i], C1 RIGHT[i]}'
}

# execute function first
print_pretty

# now make alias
alias l='print_pretty 2>/dev/null' #<-- sneaky ignore errors command here!

#=====================================================================================

html ()
{
pandoc -f markdown -t html $1 > /home/ciaran/Desktop/r.html
wait
firefox /home/ciaran/Desktop/r.html;
wait
sleep 5
rm /home/ciaran/Desktop/r.html;
}

# call function
html

#=====================================================================================

alias src='clear && source ~/.bashrc'
```

Comment: Oh... I didn't know this. If this is the case, why on earth does the printPretty function not throw a tantrum everytime?

Comment: I just tried it. It doesn't work. Still getting the error.

Comment: I just added the /dev/null statement to the html alias too and I'm still seeing the error.

Comment: Try . ~/.bash_aliases then . ~/.bashrc

Comment: As soon as I `. .bash_aliases`, it gives the error.

Comment: Your aliases need single quotes not double.  alias l='printPretty 2>/dev/null'

Comment: Please post update file then.  Also, you don't need an alias for a function if the name is the same!

Answer (score 1):

Here's to resume what the answer by tDarkCrystal brought to fruition:

So the answer is simple... I called the function the same name as the alias, so it confused itself...

I changed `html ()` to `htmlFunc ()` and now it works.

Thanks tDarkCrystal